# Trying to suspend someone from chat for 0.02 hours results in an error page

Tags: bug, chat, moderator-tools, account-suspension

I've attempted to suspend a user from chat for 1-2 minutes so I input 0.02 into the "hours" field.

The result was [this error page](https://chat.stackexchange.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/users/gag)

Comment: Dare I ask the obvious question?

Comment: OK I'll ask then. Under what circumstances would this be useful?

Comment: Either way, the input should be caught some different way than through an error page

Comment: Well, I didn't feel that more than a couple minutes were necessary. It doesn't change the result. Obviously, the user was not suspended.

Comment: I don't believe it's necessary to fix this bug, since it's now possible for mods (and ROs) to *kick* a user for a short period of time, without issuing a suspension.